# ColdFusion statements aren't being evaluated, raw code is shown instead

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to complete the "Learn ColdFusion In a Week" tutorials from the Cold Fusion website. I've set up mySQL 5.5 (on the C:/ drive) and installed ColdFusion 10 (on the E:/ drive). I completed all the setup steps and the install script (http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Installing_Sample_Files/) completed successfully.

I went through the first section of Hands on but when I create the variables using CF the test page renders as raw code instead of HTML and CF. The solution provided in the sample files also renders as raw code. I think this is a pretty simple fix but I don't know what it would be. I'm out of my depth. I don't know what more information I can provide that will make troubleshooting this easier but if you know of something please tell me.

Summary: When I add CF statements to an HTML document the page shows as raw code. I have CF 10 and mySQL 5.5.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using the built-in webserver or your own on Apache or IIS?

Comment: Can you post the URL you're calling?

Comment: file:///E:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/learncfinaweek/www/index.cfm

Comment: I am unsure of which webserver I am using. I've included a more detailed answer below.

Comment: You're not using a web server when you try to do `file:///...` - your URL should begin with `http` (or `https`) protocol. Since there's a contact form on the CF in a week website, it'd be good if you could give them feedback on this misunderstanding, so they can update the tutorials to clarify things.

Answer (score 6):

You said above that the url you are calling is file:///E:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/learncfinaweek/www/index.cfm
This is why it doesn't work as you are opening the file directly from your computer and not usong a url. Thus coldfusion is never being used.
You need to use the url to your site, e.g look at your.cfadmim url.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The file must be SERVED using an HTTP request, such as http://127.0.0.1:8500/wwwroot/learncfinaweek/www/index.cfm

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you are not requesting that the ColdFusion server process your code.  To have the ColdFusion server process your ColdFusion code, you need to ensure that your pages use the CFM extension.

Use `index.CFM` not `index.HTML`.

Comment: You can also edit your configuration so that .htm and .html pages WILL be evaluated by the CF engine.

Comment: @Evik, As part of the hands on assignment of the tutorial I changed the index.html file to index.cfm and the page rendered correctly (with example graphics, not as raw code). The problem occurred once I edited the code to create CF variables on line 1 and 2 (per the tutorial's instructions) which were later referenced to display my name and position on the page.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question and provide a thoughtful response.

Answer (score 1):

The usual answers for this are:

1. ColdFusion isn't installed, or installed incorrectly.
2. ColdFusion is installed but with the included standalone web server, and you're using another web server.
3. The web server isn't setup to process .HTML files as .cfm (as mentioned by Evik above.)

When you installed CF, it normally boots up to the Admin console. Do you remember if that worked when you installed it? 
Were you ever able to get a CF page to run (the Admin console is in CF)? 
What web server are you running?

Comment: Based on what you've said I believe ColdFusion was installed correctly because the CF Admin console loaded successfully and I was able to log in and add the blank mySQL database as a datasource during setup for the tutorial. Your second point seems the most likely to me but I don't know how to check which web server is being used. I used mySQL 5.5 and ColdFusion 10 developer version (which comes with the standalone web server i believe?). I've got screenshots of mySQL workbench and CF Admin console > datasources.

Comment: I'm confused because without any CF commands in them the pages load correctly even while having the .cfm extension but when I add a CF command the pages show as raw code, even the solution to the assignment which should be free of any errors I may have caused shows as raw code.

Thank you all for taking the time to read my question and respond with thoughtful answers. I'm having a hard time with this but I think once I figure out this issue I'll be able to complete the tutorial without too much hassle. Thank you again,

Regards,
Mark McHenry

Answer (score 0):

This is the address you need to put in your browser (assuming you used the same port):
http://localhost:8500/learncfinaweek/www/index.cfm

The file is located on your computer at E:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\learncfinaweek\www\index.cfm but in order for it to get parsed by the ColdFusion server you have installed locally, you need to access it through localhost since that is where your server is located. You'll notice that your CF admin login starts the same way:
http://localhost:8500/CFIDE/administrator/

That file also has a corresponding location: E:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE\administrator

If there is a different number after localhost then use that instead of 8500.